# passing an 2d array pointer to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I know how to pass 1D array pointer to a function by the following code

```
void fiddleWithArray(int*);   

int main(){

int list[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17};
cout << "List at 0 before being passed is... " << list[0][0] << endl;    
cout << "List at 1 before being passed is... " << list[1][0] << endl;    
fiddleWithArray(list);
cout << "List at 0 after being passed is... " << list[0][0] << endl;    
cout << "List at 1 after being passed is... " << list[1][0] << endl;    

}

void fiddleWithArray(int* input){
input[0] = 45;
input[1] = 18;
}
```

However, when I try to do something similar for a 2D array(as shown below) I get an error.

```
void fiddleWithArray (int** input);

int main ()
{
int list [10][2]={{1,3},{5,7},{9,11},{13,17},{7,4},{5,90},{9,1},{3,25}};
int ** pointer;
pointer=&list;
cout<< "List at 0 before being passed is ... "<< list[0][0]<< endl;
cout<< "List at 1 before being passed is ... "<< list[1][0]<< endl;
fiddleWithArray(pointer);
cout<< "List at 0 after being passed is ... "<< list[0][0]<< endl;
cout<< "List at 1 after being passed is ... "<< list[1][0]<< endl;
}

void fiddleWithArray(int** input)
{   
cout << input [6][1]<< endl;
}
```

The compiler gives an error saying "error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[10][2]’ to ‘int**’ in assignment
     pointer=&list;"
I am also open to alternate methods of passing a 2D array pointer to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your data structure, if you want to pass `list` to `fiddleWithArray` you can declare it as

```
void fiddleWithArray (int input[][2]);
```

and then, in the main program, call it as

```
fiddleWithArray(list);
```

There is also another problem in your program: `cout << list[0]` does not work. If you want to print the contents of the array when the first index is fixed to 0 you would write something like

```
cout << list[0][0] << " " << list[0][1]
```

If you instead intended to write the array where the *second* index is fixed to 0 or 1, then, to keep things easily, you need a short loop like

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   cout << list[i][0] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Finally, instead of using `int[][]` you may want to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)introduced in C++11.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. ur suggestion sorted out my issue.  :)

Comment: Good answer. Recommend changing `void fiddleWithArray (int input[][2]);` to `void fiddleWithArray (int input[][2], size_t len);` or something similar so `fiddleWithArray` knows when to stop iterating.

Comment: @ francesco also a small clarification. the [2] in void fiddleWithArray (int input[][2]); is it 2 because it is a 2d array or because the second parameter in list array is 2?

Comment: @McMissile the [2] in the declaration of fiddleWithArray refers to the size of the second dimension. In fact, in declaring multidimensional arrays as parameters, you have to specify the sizes of all dimensions except possibly the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
void fiddleWithArray(int input[10][2])
{
    cout << input[6][1] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int list[10][2] = {{1,3},{5,7},{9,11},{13,17},{7,4},{5,90},{9,1},{3,25}};
    int (*pointer)[10][2];
    pointer=&list;
    cout << "List at 0 before being passed is ... "<< list[0][0]<< endl;
    cout << "List at 1 before being passed is ... "<< list[1][0]<< endl;
    fiddleWithArray(*pointer);
    cout << "List at 0 after being passed is ... "<< list[0][0]<< endl;
    cout << "List at 1 after being passed is ... "<< list[1][0]<< endl;
}
```

Will be better using [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)